# How to work on both UIPopOverControl and other views in the scene?

Tags: objective-c, uipopovercontroller, uipopover

I have a requirement where I have a UIPopOverControl in my screen, where I would want to work on both the UIPopOver as well as on the other views on the screen. By default when the popover is active, it does not let me work on the other views (I had to redefine the corresponding delegate for this).

Kindly suggest ways. Please let me know in case I need to produce more info on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Well I figured out the resolution. The property passThroughViews of popovercontroller has to be set to the view where the control is required.